# How to cache DbCompiledModel (or only its metadata) in a distributed cache

Tags: wcf, caching, entity-framework-4.1, distributed-caching

I work on a Entity Framework Code First project with a large dbContext (800+ entities).

The problem I have is that it takes up to 30 seconds to build and compile the metadata for the first time and I cannot afford having all farm servers delay the first request (WCF) in such a manner, even with the help of the AppFabric WarmUp module.
An option is to cache the compiled model on a distributed cache, so other servers in the farm could take the advantage of an already existing model, when instantiating the DbContext.

Some things I found out:

- A DbCompiledModel instance cannot be serialized;
- DbCompiledModel uses an implementation of 'ICachedMetadataWorkspace' to cache its metadata, called 'CodeFirstCachedMetadataWorkspace';
- 'CodeFirstCachedMetadataWorkspace' (or even 'ICachedMetadataWorkspace') could indeed be used to provide a serializable workspace (along with the help of a 'DbDatabaseMapping.ToMetadataWorkspace' method) which to be stored as xml on the distributed cache;

Unfortunately all mentioned types are defined as internal by EF Code First (except of course DbCompiledModel) and until now I couldn't find a suitable way to cache this out of the process.

Another thing I've tried was to have a custom ObjectContext (to use it in DbContext constructor) where to programmaticaly generate/load the csdl, ssdl and msl mappings (from the db schema), but the actual views (poco classes) still remain unmapped to the overall db context.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: There are some things that you can do here, but first I want to clarify what the problem is. Usually with large models it is view generation that takes much more time that creating the actual model. So I assume that you must already be using pre-generated views here. If not then that would be the first thing to try. You can use the EF Power Tools for that. Look at the Generate Views section of this post: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2012/04/09/ef-power-tools-beta-2-available.aspx

Comment: The idea is that I already have more than 800 entities in the model, and with a large project team it would be hard to maintain and synchronize both the POCO entities (EF 4.1 code first) and pre-compiled views (thus the need for runtime generation of the precompiled views). And because the app fabric distributed cache is already in place (common cache for backend servers), the requirement was to send the pre-compiled views to the distributed cache, so each server could take them and speed up the initialization time. Thanks.

Comment: I don't believe that there is currently any way to do that. I don't believe that there is a way to extract the views that have been compiled at runtime such that you could use them anywhere else, even with access to the MetadataWorkspace. The ability to used serialized compiled model state is on our backlog but won't be in EF5.

Comment: Thanks Arthur for your time. I'll keep watching the EF evolution, serialization of db compiled model being a major initialization time decrease in a farm context.

Answer (score 0):

Try this blog post by Arthur Vickers on the EF Team: http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/04/21/code-first-building-blocks/

It specifically shows how to cache a compiled model.

Comment: I've already tried that, unfortunately once you built the ModelBuilder and compiled the DbModel, the resulting DbCompiledModel cannot be serialized in order to be transported to the distributed cache system. It can only be used/cached on the same AppDomain it was created.

Comment: i've pointed Arthur this way. If it can be done, he'll know. In the other hand, what about (a hack), creating an EDMX from the model at run time. THat's XML. YOu can move that around. Not sure what you would do with it after moving it across the wire though. ;)

Comment: @JulieLerman Could this `DbCompiledModel` be serialized to JSON saved as a file in the application directory and then be deserialized in Application_Start?  I am already generating the views and saving them to XML files.  Caching the `DbCompiledModel` might also help with my initial cold start for queries.